# Topo To Raster error 010168

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, anudem

Topo to Raster conversion tool in the 3D Analyst toolset or the Spatial Analyst toolset, gives the following error:

`ERROR 010168: Output C:\WINDOWS\system32\zpa09 already exists. Failed to execute (TopoToRaster).`

Sometimes the file referred to changes number, e.g. zpa08 or zpa05.

The file referred to is not the output file. Upon checking, including with hidden files visible, the output file cannot be seen in the location given by the error.

Parameters are as follows (optional parameters that are unchanged from default are not listed):

```
Feature Layer: Single set of uniquely spaced points containing height in Field3. Field set to Field3 and Type set to PointElevation
Output surface raster: A folder (not a .gdb).
Output cell size: 1m (set to the precise spacing of the points).
Margin in cells (optional): 1
Drainage enforcement (optional): NO_ENFORCE
Primary type of input data (optional): SPOT
```

Further attempts have been made to change result by use of changing Environment variables as follows:

```
Removal of all "Geographic Transformations Names"
Unticking of "Maintain Fully qualified field names".
"Cell Size" set explicitely to 1
"Build pyramids" and "Calculate Statistics" unchecked
```

Result unchanged.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What parameter values are you using?

Comment: Same error from same tool seen previously at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/144525/115

Comment: Have you Editing-mode on? This might cause the problem.

Comment: @PolyGeo do you recall what was on that previous question you linked to? It seems it is no longer accessible. Thank you

Comment: The Roomba has since deleted that previous question but I can still see its contents.  I do not see anything of value in it to justify undeleting it.  I recommend that you [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the parameter values you used when you saw the error.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this error (in ArcMap) by starting a new session of ArcMap, adding only the necessary layers to run the Topo To Raster, and running the Topo To Raster there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the customize menu, inside extensions, I turned the 3D Analyst off and turned it back on then it worked fine.